# Windows authentication inside the Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, reporting-services, azure-pipelines

I currently have a powershell script that automatically uploads a report file (*.rdl) to a SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) server.

I'm implementing Azure DevOps to CI/CD report files whenever a new report file is uploaded to the repository.

The above mentioned powershell script works without problems on the local machine that has passed Windows authentication on the SSRS server.

My question is, how do I get authenticated when I upload this script to my Azure devops pipeline?

In this case, is there any way to get the Azure devops pipeline to get windows authentication from the SSRS server?

Comment: You could either create an Environment -> Pipelines -> Environments or install a vsts self hosted agent on your SSRS server to run the jobs on it

Comment: 1. Configure Azure Devops with Self-Hosted agents 2. Save your username and password as variables(Secrets) / Environments in your pipeline. 3. Execute your script as script block inside Invoke-Command and pass the variables as arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DillyB I assume that you guide me to use a self-hosted agent to use windows authentication on my local machine. But if I'm considering using Microsoft Host Agent, is there a workaround? Presumably, in this case, the VM will be destroyed after use, so I'm guessing it will need something other method.

Comment: Is this SSRS server in Azure environment or in on-premises? Does it have a public ip to reach it out from MS hosted Az Devops Agent VM? If it is in On-premise server then it is good to have a self-hosted agent and deployment group. So that passing credentials over public network can be avoided.

Comment: SSRS does not need to have a public IP address only internet outgoing connection in order to be added on the self hosted agent pool. By installing the agent on this machine you do not need to authenticate with credentials, you can run the pipelines on it without password. The only password that is required is a PAT in order to setup the self hosted agent